# css and js url not working on base file thymeleaf by layout decorate

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i have a base.html where i have put on my all css and js file and it's working fine when i define url without "/".

Here is my code 
my controller

```
@GetMapping("/department/list")
public String getAllDepartment(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("departments", repository.findAll());
    return "department/list";
}
```

when hit define url only "/list" it's working fine and all css and jss working well but when define "/department/list" this url my css and jss not load.

in my view
here is my base.html

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="no-outlines" 
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <title>Meetup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{assets/css/style.css}">
    </head>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
       <main class="main--container">
           <section class="main--content" 
                layout:fragment="content">
           </section>
       </main>
   </div>
  <script th:src="@{assets/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{assets/js/main.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my list.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{base}">
<head>
    <title>Department</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="main--content" layout:fragment="content">
    <div class="row gutter-20">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Department Information</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="records--list" data-title="Orders Listing">
                    <table id="recordsListView">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order No</th>
                            <th>Order ID</th>
                            <th>Purchesed On</th>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                            <th>Ship To</th>
                            <th>Total Price</th>
                            <th>Payment</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th class="not-sortable">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my project file structure
[image]

Comment: Is everything working fine in `base.html` ?

Comment: yes working fine when url define "/list" or "/department" but when i define "/department/list" this url then css and jss not loaded

Comment: Actually I am little confused! In which html page css is not loading ?? `base.html` or `list.html` ?

Comment: i think base.html because all css and js loaded from it  and  i have decorated base layout from list.html

Comment: Try using all `html` page page in same level. That means all html page in one folder for testing purpose!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** : You should replace `assets/js/jquery.min.js` with `/assets/js/jquery.min.js`. You've missed the / at the beginning.

In your case is taking the relative url: it will try `http://localhost:8080/department/list/assets/js/jquery.min.js` and this resource does not exist.

You should use / at the beginning of your path to tell spring that you need absolute resource.The returned resource will be `http://localhost:8080/assets/js/jquery.min.js`